# Stepping through code in Google Apps Script (equivalent VBA-GAS )

Tags: vba, debugging, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

When writing my VBA macros I often used "F8" so as to debug the macro line by line. Is there a similar feature in Google Apps Script?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Similar, but not the same.

Google Apps Script is developed in a dedicated IDE<sup>1</sup> called the **Script Editor**, which provides support for single-step execution and breakpoints, among other things.
[image: Screenshot - Script Editor]

For a quick introduction to debugging using the IDE, see [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pEb-93pDHWU). The [Troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting) section of the online documentation includes a quick overview of the basics.

#### Debugging Functions with parameters

In the IDE you can select any function in your script for execution, and then select the "run" or "Debug" icons to start. Unfortunately, there is no way to pass parameters to a function this way, so here are a few ways you can deal with that.

1. Set defaults. There are [numerous ways to define defaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148901/is-there-a-better-way-to-do-optional-function-parameters-in-javascript) in javascript, here is a picture of the debugger operating on a function using the simplest of them. The function `toText()` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17092883/1677912) accepts a number as a parameter, so for this example we are forcing the default value to `21`. The picture shows the debugger paused at line 40; if we continue stepping through the function we expect to end up with a result `s == 'Twenty-one'`.

   [image: Screenshot - OR for default]
2. Write a test function. This is a better approach than setting defaults, because it allows you to write multiple test cases, and it avoids polluting your target function with debug code. As an example, the target function `flipFlopAndFly()` and its test function `test_flipFlopAndFly()` were provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16999141/1677912). The test function accesses the spreadsheet to provide appropriate data for testing the target, so we can easily modify the data for different tests. *Note also, this function includes error checking, so it would not be appropriate to test by forcing default values.*

There are many variations on these basic patterns, so feel free to adapt them to your own situation. It will help your debugging capability to think *while you are writing* about how you would step through your code:

- Is each important object and value stored in a `var`, so you can see it?
- Is your function result (return value) in a `var`?

#### Custom Functions

When developing or debugging custom functions that will be called from a spreadsheet, remember that you cannot "jump" into the IDE. If you need to step through the script, you will need to work entirely within the IDE to observe execution of your code. You can use the techniques described above to debug custom functions.

---

<sup>1</sup> [Integrated Development Environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)

Comment: I've found that some functions and break points are hard to get to especially when functions are passed as parameters (Array.map etc) If I need to check something, then I will force an error. `o.o;` Is inserted strategically, and then I press the bug button to run my test function.

Comment: @fooby - I'd need to see an example to understand the "strategic location", and why a breakpoint can't be used. I use other techniques as well (GsUnit, for example), but since the basic "how to" has been asked here several times, I figured starting with the basics was worthwhile.

Comment: I guess, in the times of the ES6 the best fit way is just:
`function toText(num=21) { ... }`