# Is there an alternative to the implementation of Logger class?

Tags: google-apps-script

After you run the script you get a chance to view the log in a modal 
window, and even that is broken, because it does NOT log the entire script session, usually just the last 1 or 2 calls to log!
Is there not some means of having the log continuously stream to another window, or file even. 
I mean whoever implemented this, seriously, face palm!
I don't care that the apps script debugger no longer works, but please a logger that can LOG!
Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because while this might be a valid rant it's still a rant and not a question.

Comment: write your own to log into a spreadsheet.

Comment: Fred, don't be scared off by the negative tone of @EikePierstorff's comment - now that you've blown off steam, edit the title and question, because it's a good, valid question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's an alternative - the [BetterLog library](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/betterlog) lets you log from multiple sources into a spreadsheet, in pretty much real-time.

See more in [How do I run Server-side functions using HtmlService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17958298/how-do-i-run-server-side-functions-using-htmlservice/17961595#17961595).