# HTML-service pages to call server-side Apps Script functions with dialog box

Tags: html, google-apps-script, client-server

I've tried following the model for [Client-to-Server Communication on Google Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication), using unlike in the model, a [modal dialog](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/#serve_html_as_a_google_docs_sheets_or_forms_user_interface).

**Model Code:**

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function doSomething() {
  Logger.log('I was called!');
}
```

**Model HTML:**

```
<script>
  google.script.run.doSomething();
</script>
```

**My Code:**

```
function openDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showModalDialog(html, 'My Dialog');
}

function doSomething() {
  Logger.log('I was called!');
}
```

My HTML is the same as the model HTML.

Running this script however, does not call the Logger as expected. Did I do this wrong?

Comment: As I recall, HTML doesn't trigger the Logger, try returning a value then logging it with console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been reported as [Issue 5177](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5177), star it for updates & to get attention for the problem.

There are circumstances where we should not expect the Logger to operate, for example when using a Time-based Trigger function, because there is no association between the execution instance and a debugger instance to record logs.

However, that's not the case here. We should have the ability to use the logger here, but it's unreliable. The logs *do* show up, *sometimes*:

[image: screenshot]

Because of this behaviour, I use the [BetterLog library](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/custom-methods/betterlog) to record logs to a spreadsheet when debugging. (You can even invoke it via `google.script.run` to log to the spreadsheet from within your client-side JavaScript. See more about that in [How do I run Server-side functions using HtmlService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17958298/how-do-i-run-server-side-functions-using-htmlservice/17961595#17961595).)

Comment: Although this BetterLog seems to conflict with the onOpen() function (the custom menu doesn't show up).

Comment: The conflict with onOpen() is worked around by not specifying the spreadsheet key (https://code.google.com/p/google-script-examples/issues/detail?id=43&q=onOpen&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Opened%20Summary)